# How can I query how many decimal places does a Substrate asset have?

Tags: polkadot-js, token

For example, DOT has 10 but can I check it in Polkadot JS Apps? I want to apply it to all parachain assets.

Answer (score 3):

The `system_properties` RPC call returns the on-chain properties for the connected chain.

Additionally, if using the JS API, it is also extracted and available on `api.registry.chainDecimals`, `api.registry.chainSS58` and `api.registry.chainTokens`. (For each parachain, you need to get it from the chain itself)

Answer (score 2):

for native asset like `DOT` in polkadot is defined in chain spec and you can check here https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fpolkadot.api.onfinality.io%2Fpublic-ws#/settings/metadata

for multiple fungible asset chain like `statemine` you may check it from storage in `asset` module